# How to display checkbox in Kendo Grid column

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I am trying to display a checkbox in my grid but I keep running into an error.
My checkbox template is this:`{
                            field: "IsForeign",
                            title: "Is <br/> Foreign",
                            width: "120px",
                            dataType: "bool",
                            template: '<input type="checkbox" #= IsForeign == "true" ? checked="checked" : "" # />'
                        }`
However I keep getting an error that 'IsForeign' is undefined.  When I run the grid without the checkbox template everything renders correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to define define IsForeign in grid schema model and replace your code with this.

```
<input type="checkbox" #= IsForeign? \'checked="checked"\' : "" # >
```

I hope it will help you :)